# Is there a better way to build many different URLs?

Tags: swift

I am working on building a framework to connect to a specific API and will need to build a lot of different paths. My current setup is using an Enum for returning a URL, which works pretty well for the most part. My only problem I have with this approach is there will be a *lot* of different cases (~30 total) by the time I'm done. I was wondering if anyone has a better solution?

```
enum API {
   var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: "https://api.example.com")!
    }

    case user
    case emails
    case posts
    case post(id: String)
    // etc . . .
}

extension API: Path {
    func appendPathComponent(_ string: String) -> URL {
        return baseURL.appendingPathComponent(string)
    }
    var url: URL {
        switch self {
        case .user: return baseURL
        case .emails: return appendPathComponent("email")
        case .posts: return appendPathComponent("posts")
        case .post(let id): return appendPathComponent(id)
        // etc
        }
    }
}

// call site
let url = API.emails.url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would turn this around the same way that `Notification.Name` does. Make these extensions on URL:

```
extension URL {
    static let apiBase = URL(string: "https://api.example.com")!

    static let apiUser = apiBase
    static let apiEmails = apiBase.appendingPathComponent("email")
    static let apiPosts  = apiBase.appendingPathComponent("posts")
    static func apiPost(id: String) -> URL { return apiBase.appendingPathComponent(id) }

}
```

Then calling it is just:

```
let x = URL.apiEmails
```

And in cases where `URL` is known, you don't even have to include that:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: .apiEmails)
```

or

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: .apiPost(id: "123"))
```